# CSS Flex menu with submenu direction and line break

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Considering the following menu code [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ozsgwv79/1/):

```
<div class="menu">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Logo</li>
    <li>
      Services
      <div class="menu-submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>Very big text here in this option</li>
          <li>Option</li>
          <li>Option 2</li>
          <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Support</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu nav ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu nav ul li:first-child {
  height: 30px;
}

.menu nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.menu nav ul li:hover:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.menu nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-submenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu nav ul li:hover .menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-submenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-submenu ul li {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

a. How do I make the submenu to open on vertical, not horizontal ?

b. How do I allow the submenu text not to brake (open with greater width that its parent) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) You correctly set `flex-direction: column` on `.menu-submenu ul`. The problem is you also set `flex-direction: row` on `.menu nav ul` with equal (but applied) **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. To correct this, simply give your `.menu-submenu ul` selector more specificity (by changing it to `.menu-submenu > ul` for example).

b) Your `.menu nav ul li:first-child` gets applied to **both** the navbar and the submenu. Due to the `height` and `padding` restrictions, this causes the display of the submenu to get messed up. I believe you only want to apply it to the main navbar. As such, simply change this rule to make use of the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**, as `.menu nav > ul > li:first-child`.

You'll want to apply `>` to either side of `ul` to target your navbar. To target your submenu, you should use `.menu .menu-submenu > ul` and `.menu .menu-submenu > ul > li` so that you don't get confused about which menu gets targetted.

Here's an example showcasing the submenu vertical, along with removing all other rules that were (likely) incorrectly applied to it:

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu nav > ul > li:first-child {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu nav > ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu nav > ul > li:first-child {
  height: 30px;
}

.menu nav > ul > li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.menu nav > ul > li:hover:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.menu nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-submenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu nav ul li:hover .menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu .menu-submenu > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu .menu-submenu > ul > li {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Logo</li>
    <li>
      Services
      <div class="menu-submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>Very big text here in this option</li>
          <li>Option</li>
          <li>Option 2</li>
          <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Support</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly how it is breaking? The text `Very big text here in this option` is entirely visible within the dropdown item.

Comment: The text `Very big text here in this option` is visible, but is breaking into more than one line. I need it to be in the same line (no wrapping), and for that it will increase the submenu div weight. This is a point I'm not being able to solve...

Answer (score 2):

You can make it nicer with less code:

```css
.menu, .menu * {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

.menu {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul li {
  margin: 0 5px; /* adjust */
  padding: 5px; /* adjust */
}

.menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.menu ul li:hover:not(:first-child) {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.menu ul li:hover .menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-submenu {
  display: none;
  position: relative; /* added */
}

.menu-submenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; /* modified; adjust; needs to match the padding of the ".menu ul li" */
  left: -5px; /* added; adjust; needs to match the padding of the ".menu ul li" (negative) */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-submenu ul li {
  width: 100%; /* added */
  padding: 5px; /* adjust */
  white-space: nowrap; /* added */
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Logo</li>
    <li>
      Services
      <div class="menu-submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>Very big text here in this option</li>
          <li>Option 1</li>
          <li>Option 2</li>
          <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Support</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Otherwise the point is in using the `white-space: nowrap` to prevent line breaking and  `width: 100%` to make them even in width. Since the `.menu-submenu ul` has `position: absolute`, `position: relative` needs to be on its *parent element*.